# How to reference the alias of a table in the EXCLUDED of an UPSERT in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

I want to reference table "b" in the EXCLUDED of the following UPSERT, but when I want to do it I get 'There is an entry for table "b", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query'.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_acc_payable_balances AS b ("supplierId", total, "balanceNotdue", "createdBy")
SELECT r."supplierId", po.total, po.total, r."updatedBy"
FROM tbl_wh_receptions r, tbl_sh_purchase_orders po
WHERE   r."xmlUploaded"         = 1         AND
        r."completedMaterial"   = 1         AND
        r."purchaseOrderId"     = po.id     AND
        r."updatedAt"           = (SELECT MAX("updatedAt") FROM tbl_wh_receptions)
ON CONFLICT ("supplierId") DO UPDATE
SET b.total = b.total + excluded.b.total,
    b."balanceNotdue" = b."balanceNotdue" + excluded.b."balanceNotdue";
```

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. The alias `b` will reference the "current value" of that column in the table. The alias `excluded` will reference the column value from the "source" of the INSERT statement. You can only reference one or the other, not both at the same time. So you most probably want `excluded.total`

Comment: You can not use the table alias of the target table on the left hand side of the SET assignment. Soe `set b.total = ...` should be `set total = ...`